# awk split on a different token

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to initialize an array from a string split using awk.
I am expecting the tokens be delimited by ",", but somehow they don't.

The input is a string returned by curl from the address http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=the+campaign
I've tried to remove any extra carriage return or things that could cause confusion, but in all clients I have checked it looks to be a single line string.

```
{"Title":"The Campaign","Year":"2012","Rated":"R", ...
```

and this is the ouput

```
    -metadata {"Title":"The **-metadata** Campaign","Year":"2012","Rated":"R","....
```

It should have been

```
   -metadata {"Title":"The Campaign"
```

Here's my piece of code:

```
__tokens=($(echo $omd_response | awk -F ',' '{print}'))
for i in "${__tokens[@]}"
  do
    echo "-metadata" $i"
done
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: did you try `awk -F, ....`? `print` will print the entire line. If you want to print a specific column use `print $i` where `i` is a column

Comment: Yes, I have tried with no luck. I also tried to use {print $0}. I need all tokens to be part of the array.

Comment: `print $0` is same as `print` which will print the entire line. You need to use `print $1` if you want the 1st column.

Comment: Your problem is also in the display: `for i in "${__tokens[@]}"` will put __tokens[@] within `""`, and therefore regroups it ... so in effect it does a `for i in "everything_at_once"` and will loop only once. See my answer for an safer alternative

Comment: Watch out for data like the following: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0183505 (the `Title` attribute contains a comma). You should look at a [command-line JSON parser like jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: I finally accepted the suggestion to use jq, however I am confused on how to iterate trough the response.

Answer (score 2):

I would take seriously the comment by @cbuckley: Use a json-aware tool rather than trying to parse the line with simple string tools. Otherwise, your script will break if a quoted-string has an comma inside, for example.

At any event, you don't need `awk` for this exercise, and it isn't helping you because the way `awk` breaks the string up is only of interest to `awk`. Once the string is printed to `stdout`, it is still the same string as always. If you want the shell to use `,` as a field delimiter, you have to tell the shell to do so.

Here's one way to do it:

```
(
  OLDIFS=$IFS
  IFS=,
  tokens=($omd_response)
  IFS=$OLDIFS

  for token in "${tokens[@]}"; do
    # something with token
  done
)
```

The `(` and `)` are just to execute all that in a subshell, making the shell variables temporaries. You can do it without.

Answer (score 1):

First, please accept my apologies: I don't have a recent bash at hand so I can't try the code below (no arrays!)

But it *should* work, or if not you should be able to tweak it to work (or ask underneath, providing a little context on what you see, and I'll help fix it)

```
nb_fields=$(echo "${omd_response}" | tr ',' '\n' | wc -l | awk '{ print $1 }')
  #The nb_fields will be correct UNLESS ${omd_response} contains a trailing "\", 
  #in which case it would be 1 too big, and below would create an empty 
  # __tokens[last_one], giving an extra `-metadata ""`. easily corrected if it happens.

#the code below assume there is at least 1 field... You should maybe check that.

#1) we create the __tokens[] array
for field in $( seq  1 $nb_fields )
do
   #optionnal: if field is 1 or $nb_fields, add processing to get rid of the { or } ?
   ${__tokens[$field]}=$(echo "${omd_response}" | cut -d ',' -f ${field})
done

#2) we use it to output what we want
for i in $( seq  1 $nb_fields )
do
   printf '-metadata "%s" '   "${__tokens[$i]}"
      #will output all on 1 line. 
      #You could add a \n just before the last ' so it goes each on different lines
done
```

so I loop on field numbers, instead of on what could be some space-or-tab separated values

Comment: if you really insist on awk, the `cut -d',' -f${field}` could be `awk -F ',' -v nb=${field} '{ print $nb }'`